# How to get server to get except form from client

Tags: php, web

I am building a website for some friends of mine who run this non-profit local business. I want to allow them to write articles and stuff like that without having to bother me to write up a whole new HTML page and then copy/paste the article (or worse, have to hand type the whole thing myself). This is the first time I have really done this and though I am still learning i want to make it look professional.

Right now I have a tool on the website built in php that copies custom template HTML files as well as some scripts that do things like convert php vars into Javascript vars, places in the corresponding data such as the page name, the article name, and the article itself, and create a link to the articles in a page dedicated to finding articles. And then places those HTML and scripts into their own folder.

My question is how do I tell the server(from the clients side) to update itself with the new folders and files. In other words, when the user fills out the form(page name, article name, article text) and then submits it, how do I get the root folder to on the server to actually do the copying and processing.

My plan is to use hostinger for hosting, and they support php. I just need to know how to get the server to except the form request when the user posts the article. Right now for testing purposes I am using XAMMP and all the local host stuff.

Note: when I say user, i only mean the people I am making the site for. It will not be an open tool that anyone can use to write articles. If I did that I would:

1 need to spend extra money in a better plan for more disc space.

2 i would use a database to store all of those articles.

I don't wanna use a database. I just want to update the root folder with the proper articles when they submit them.

Edit---

I was told to be more specific.

My question is. Is there a standard procedure to sending a request to a server from a client, and how do I link a client to the server. E.g do I need to link them through ip addresses. Or server/client names. Or something like that.

Comment: At a high level, you do this like you do literally anything on the Internet between the client and server: You issue a request. It's up to you to build something to respond to the request, and something to issue the request. You need to ask a much more specific question if you want a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel?
Even for flatfile CMS there are premade solutions. E.g. [Pico](http://picocms.org/docs/)

A quick google search could come up with a better and more secure solution than you probably could currently come up with.

Post post remark: I regard this as the better alternative, since you made clear that this is not meant as a learning exercise.